# how to render adobe after effect stardust video as MP4?

Tags: adobe, render, effect, after-effects

I created the whole composition using Stardust and added effects and layers
NOTE: I am using a free & trial version of Stardust. so the left panel of the project preview shows (DEMODEMO & For evaluation) also in the main screen but in right panel preview video works fine
but when I render this video only a black screen appears.